# C++ input loop gives "Process finished with exit code 11" Error

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, clion

The following is the start of my C++ code. I'd like to be able to type in 5 inputs and get them stored in the vector. However the code breaks on the double array element access. How can I fix this and why is it breaking? The error I'm getting on my IDE (CLion) is "could not find operator[]".

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setprecision;

using std::sort;
using std::streamsize;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main () {
    vector<int> inputVec;
    int x;
    while (cin >> x && inputVec.size() < 5) {
        inputVec.push_back(x);
        cout << inputVec.size() << endl;
    }
    sort(inputVec.begin(), inputVec.end());
    cout << "before if 1" << endl;
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = inputVec.size();
    cout << "before if 3" << endl;
    if (size < 4) {
        cout << "too few inputs";
    } else {
        cout << "calculating quartiles" << endl;
        int quartileSize = size / 4;
        int leftOvers = size - quartileSize * 4;
        int count = 0;
        vector<vector<int>> quartiles(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < quartileSize; j++) {
                quartiles[i][j] = inputVec[count++];
            }
        }
```

Comment: `quartiles[i][j]` doesn't exist yet

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Isn't it defined 3 lines up?from the issue line. "vector<vector<int>> quartiles(4);"

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> quartiles(4);` will make 4 `vector<int>`s and no `ints` to go into those `vector<int>`s. You want something along the lines of `vector<vector<int>> quartiles(4, vector<int>(quartileSize));`

Comment: Better wording: Think of `vector<vector<int>> quartiles(4);` like you would `int quartiles[4][0];` The size of the second dimension has not been established.

Comment: The inner `for` loop uses `j` as the counter, but the condition checks `i`.  The loop will either execute not at all, or endlessly (which will probably result in a segmentation fault/SIGSEGV/signal 11).